# Z-Score and stats

Tags: statistics

At 45 mph, the braking distance of an automobile has a mean of 50 feet and a standard deviation of 3.5 feet. Find the braking distance that corresponds to a z-score of 2.0. This is the boundary of an unusually long braking distance.

I think it's .9772? Is that right?

Comment: You seem to have a probability not a breaking distance. Hint $z=\frac {x-\mu}{\sigma}$

Comment: so i would do 45-50/3.5 to get -1.42?

Comment: No. Look at the units subtracting feet from miles per hour doesn't make sense. Solve $2=\frac{x-50}{3.5}$

Comment: would it be 57?

Comment: Yes. It's a good idea to give the units aswell, it helps to check your answer is sensible.